# How to limit Service Account to only be able to access Google Drive?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I need to make an app (without UI) that uploads some files to a shared folder on Google Drive (I don't need to work with multiple accounts). From what I found, Service Account appears to be a good solution for accessing the Drive API. I want to limit my newly created Service Account to only be allowed to use Google Drive, but I can't figure out how to do that. I know that I can create a role and assign it to the account, but I have no idea which permissions (if any) relate to the Drive API.

Comment: this might help.
https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/dont-fear-authentication-google-drive-edition

Comment: Service accounts are not a good solution for accessing the Drive API. Google publishes warnings about this. Read the red text in this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority

Comment: What have you tried so far ? what were the results ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B I tried creating a service account without specifying a role or permissions, but then the service account had all the permissions, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. I tried searching for permissions that relate to Google Drive, so I could create a role that has only those permissions, but I wasn't able to find any and I decided to write this question.

Answer (score 1):

To create perrmission for a Service Account to access File or a Shared drive, follow the below guide:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create

The guide has an API on the right which helps you create methods to perform calls on live data.